# How can get a count with nested objects with a certain property?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, lodash

Okay so I'm using angular to get a json saved to my computer to recreate a github gradebook.

I can get the data with my $http request but for the love of me all I want is to get a count of the number of issues with the label "Not Yet".

Here is the javascript:

```
$http.get('/api/github/repos/issues/all_issues/00All.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data[0]);
    var counter = 0;
    for(var index = 0; index < response.data.length; index++) {
      if(response.data[index].labels[0].name == "Not Yet") {
        counter++;
      };
    };
    console.log(counter);
  });
```

That's the latest try, I also tried using lodash to get it earlier:

```
$http.get('/api/github/repos/issues/all_issues/00All.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    mile.notYet.width = _.forEach(response.data, function(n){
      var counter = 0;
      if(_.result(_.find(n.labels[0], 'name')) == "Not Yet") {
        counter++;
      }
      console.log(counter);
      counter = ((counter/10) * 100) + '%';
    });
  });
```

This is a bit of the json data:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TheIronYard--Orlando/2015--SUMMER--FEE/issues/11",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TheIronYard--Orlando/2015--SUMMER--FEE/issues/11/labels{/name}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TheIronYard--Orlando/2015--SUMMER--FEE/issues/11/comments",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TheIronYard--Orlando/2015--SUMMER--FEE/issues/11/events",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/TheIronYard--Orlando/2015--SUMMER--FEE/issues/11",
    "id": 73013825,
    "number": 11,
    "title": "00 -- Brace Yourself -- BEN GRIFFITH",
    "user": {
      "login": "Epicurean306",
      "id": 11682684,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11682684?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/Epicurean306",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Epicurean306/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "labels": [
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/TheIronYard--Orlando/2015--SUMMER--FEE/labels/Not%20Yet",
        "name": "Not Yet",
        "color": "e11d21"
      }
    ],
```

As you can see the labels property is an object, nested in an array, nested in an object, nested in an array, real lovely. Putting labels[0] results in an error for me each time and doesn't get me a count. Can anybody tell me where I'm messing up please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a solution that includes lodash, which is much more performant than the native high order functions then you can try this solution below:

```
var size = _(response.data)
   .pluck('labels')
   .flatten()
   .where({ name: 'Not Yet' })
   .size();
```

UPDATE:

If you want it to be more reusable, you can save a reference for a cloned chained sequence and simply supply another array for that cloned sequence.

```
var data1 = [/*array from data1*/];
var data2 = [/*array from data2*/];

var notYetSequence = _(data1)
  .pluck('labels')
  .flatten()
  .where({ name: 'Not Yet' });

notYetSequence.size(); // returns data 1 count
notYetSequence.plant(data2).size(); // returns data 2 count
```

Comment: Of course :). The code above lazily evaluates the code. In fact is only performs one loop. One reference would be [this](http://filimanjaro.com/blog/2014/introducing-lazy-evaluation/).

Comment: So if it's a 1 loop statement vs 3 statements, it's rather a "just a very little more performant" not "much more"

Comment: Regardless, how would you quantify "just a very little more performant" and "much more"? These are just a play of words..

Comment: It is :-) There is no filtering and having lazy evaluation wouldn't help here since you still need to get the size of the total collection. So the only benefit lodash may potentially give is memory allocation for temporary arrays, which for less than dozens of thousands of operations per second and for arrays less than 10s of thousands of elements is negligible. I agree that lodash may improve performance, but in very specific use cases. And definitely not in general.

Comment: You are probably right, and perhaps that is arguable. In terms of benefits, you can say that there are a lot of factors that lodash contributes to: browser compatibility, conciseness, readability and this "little bit of performance boost".

Comment: Agreed. PS: Just to clarify: I'm not a lodash hater, I use it almost every day actually :-)

Comment: Btw, it worth mentioning that correctness of this solution is based on the fact that every item has exactly 0 or 1 label with the given name and will produce wrong results if for some reason there are 2+ elements that match predicate (that assumption (which, actually, in fact fair in this particular case) helped to make this solution much more condensed than the "robust" one)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lodash for the task

```
var cnt = response.data
    .map(function(i) { return i.labels; })
         // here we extract labels object only (and get an array of arrays of objects)
    .map(function(i) { return i.filter(function(l) { return l.name == 'Not yet'; }).length; })
         // then for every nested array we return a number of items with 
         // Not Yet names (and get an array of numbers)
    .filter(function(c) { return c > 0; })
         // then we filter issues that don't have one (and still get an array of numbers)
    .length;
         // and finally get length (which is a number)
```

Comment: If I find this code in your homework, @gatorpazz, I'd better find an explanation. ;)

Comment: Also, preferable to use Lodash for cross-browser compatibility: not all browser implementations provide the Iteration methods on `Array`. For example, `filter` is only in IE9+: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @ALtheX–the *map* and *filter* functionality is very easily replaced with a for loops (which will execute faster too).

Comment: I think the biggest issue in regard to performance is the construction of so many temporary arrays (two *map*s and two *filter*s) and all the function calls: apart from *map* and *filter* there are 4 callbacks. Compare that to a plain for loop where the only function call is to test for "Not yet" once per *label* object, either using a regular expression or *indexOf*.

Comment: @RobG my mind was shifted to stream processing and reactive+functional programming, I cannot write imperative loops anymore ;'-( PS: +1'd you

Comment: Good news! [Lodash provides a chaining interface](https://lodash.com/docs#_) that combines functional operations.

Answer (score 1):

As a comparison, a plain for loop looks like:

```
  var data = response.data;
  var count = 0;
  var re = /not yet/i;

  for (var a, i=0, iLen=data.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    a = data[i].labels;
    for (var j=0, jLen=a.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      if (re.test(a[j].name)) ++count;
    }
  }
```

So really not a lot of code either way, the for loop will be compatible with every browser ever (though using xmlHTTPRequest means at least ed 3+) and fastest… untested of course. ;-)